# Real Analysis fundamental theorems of Calculus contradiction?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

**Evaluate:** $\frac{d}{dx} \int_{0}^{x} x^3t^3dt.$

**Solution:** $\frac{d}{dx} \int_{0}^{x} x^3t^3dt = \frac{7x^6}{4}.$

**Proof:**

Consider the function's $F:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $f:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, define: $F(t) = \frac{1}{4}x^3t^4 + c$ and $f(t) = x^3t^3.$ Observe that by proposition 4.7 F is differentiable on (a,b) and $F'(t) = x^3t^3 = f(t)$ for all x in $(a,b).$ Moreover by the polynomial property (proposition 2.17): F is continuous on [a,b] and f is continuous on [a,b], so by theorem 3.14 we know f is bounded and by theorem 6.18 f is integrable. We satisfy the criteria in the first fundamental theorem of calculus (theorem 6.22) hence:

$\frac{d}{dx} \int_{0}^{x} x^3t^3dt = \frac{d}{dx} [F(x) - F(0)] = \frac{d}{dx} \frac{1}{4}x^7 = \frac{7}{4}x^6.$

But by the second fundamental theorem of calculus (theorem 6.29):

$\frac{d}{dx} \int_{0}^{x} x^3t^3dt = f(x) = x^6 \neq F'(x) = \frac{7}{4}x^6$. **Contradiction. WHY!?**

(Textbook: Advanced Calculus - Patrick M. Fitzpatrick, Chapter 6.6)

**Edit**
Thank you everyone for your help, I managed to figure it out from all of the advice!

Comment: It is not true that $\frac{d}{d x}\int_0^x f(t) d t = f(x)$ when $f(t)$ also depends on $x$.

Comment: $f(t)=x^3t^3$ is not a valid definition because $x^3t^3$ also depends on $x.$

Comment: Try $\int_0^xx^3t^3dt=x^3\int_0^xt^3dt=u(x)v(x)$, where $u(x)=x^3$ and $v(x)=\int_0^xt^3dt$, then apply $(uv)'=u'v+uv'$

Comment: @Gribouillis I don't understand, how would I make it not depend on x?

Comment: @Asigan But then I am not using the fundamental theorem of calculus 2 (the differentiating integrals one) which I need to use?

Comment: There is no way to make it not depend on $x$ when it depends on $x$. In this specific example you can factor the $x^3$ outside the integral as @Asignan suggests. This is the best thing to do.

Comment: @user2328170 Well, you need to use this theorem when determining $v'(x)$. By the way you should read again how the theorem is stated. $F(x)=\int_a^xf(u)du$ and $f(u)$ continuous at $u=x_0\Longrightarrow$ $F'(x_0)=f(x_0)$. Speaking in a less rigorous way, $x$, the boundary point of the interval on which we do the integral, should not appear in $f$ ,the function being intergrated. Namely, to apply the theorem, $f$ should be an one-variable function of the intergrated variable $u$.

Comment: @Asigan The theorem from the textbook verbatim "Suppose that the function f:[a,b] --> R is continuous. Then $\frac{d}{dx} \int_{a}^{b} f = f(x)$ for all x in (a,b)."

(Bottom of page 168: https://books.google.com/books?id=4hhFXPdTXwoC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Comment: @Asigan You are the real mvp, I figured it out thanks to you! My biggest pet-peeve with this book is that it does too minimalistic of a job explaining concepts. The book is outstanding if you are refreshing your memory, but awful if it is your first time studying Real Analysis! For example, check out the chapters on sequences, by his definition of a sequence, the sequence {1/(n-7)} is undefined, however any other real analysis text explains that said sequence begins from n=8 and is actually equivalent to {1/n} which begins from n=1. Anyway, that is my rant and thank you!

Answer (score 1):

When $f$ depends on $x$ and $t$ one has
\begin{equation}
\frac{d}{d x}\int_0^x f(x, t) d t = f(x, x) + \int_0^x\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x, t) d t
\end{equation}
In your case it gives
\begin{equation}
\frac{d }{d x}\int_0^x x^3 t^3 d t
= x^6 + \int_0^x 3 x^2 t^3 dt
\end{equation}
which is different from $x^6$.

Comment: I appreciate your reply, however I do not understand. My text did not introduce the notation f(x,t) yet. It did however introduce f((x,t)) which denotes the image of f on the open interval (x,t).

Comment: Never mind, the notation $f(x, t)$ is only a way to indicate that a quantity $f$ depends on two parameters $x$ and $t$.

Comment: Suppose f(t) = 2t, then the solution f(x) = 2x is correct. f depends on the parameter t. However when f(t) = x*2t why are we treating this any different? Within the integral we are integrating w/r to t, so we treat x as a constant, do we not?

Comment: @Macabbi Yes, when you integrate with respect to $t$, $x$ is a constant, but when you differentiate with respect to $x$, it is no longer a constant.

Comment: Okay, thank you. But suppose I must use the fundamental theorem of calculus (the one involving differentiating integrals). How would one utilize it when they need to solve: $\frac{d}{dx} \int_{a}^{b}f(x,t)dt$ ?

Comment: @Macabbi The elementary theorem does not apply to the case where $f$ depends on both $x$ and $t$. In that case, one must use Leibniz integral rule https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule . It is the formula that I wrote in this answer.

Comment: Thank you! I took $x^3$ out of the integral and differentiated using chain rule, the answer comes out the same: $x^6 + \frac{3}{4}x^6 = \frac{7}{4}x^6$. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It should be noted that the [Leibniz Integral Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule) deals with integrals like the one in question.
In the current example the integral takes the following form (with a slight generalization).
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx} \, \int_{0}^{x} (x \, t)^n \, dt &= (x \, x)^n \, \frac{d}{dx}(x) - (x \cdot 0)^n \, \frac{d}{dx}(0) + \int_{0}^{x} \left[ \frac{d}{dx}(x \, t)^n \right] \, dt \\
&= x^{2n} + n \, x^{n-1} \, \int_{0}^{x} t^{n} \, dt \\
&= x^{2 n} + n \, x^{n-1} \cdot \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1} \\
&= \frac{2 n + 1}{n+1} \, x^{2 n}.
\end{align}

A straight forward evaluation takes the form
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx} \, \int_{0}^{x} (x \, t)^n \, dt &= \frac{d}{dx} \, \left( \frac{x^{2 n + 1}}{n+1} \right) = \frac{2n+1}{n+1} \, x^{2n}. 
\end{align}

By using a corollary of the [Fundamental Theorem of Calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus), namely,
$$ \int_{a}^{b} f(t) \, dt = F(b) - F(a), $$
where $F(x)$ is the anti-derivative of $f(x)$, then
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx} \, \int_{0}^{x} (x \, t)^n \, dt &= \frac{d}{dx} \, \left[ x^n \, (F(x) - F(0) ) \right] \\
&= \frac{d}{dx} \, \left[ x^n \, \left(\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1} - \frac{0^{n+1}}{n+1}\right) \right] \\
&= \frac{d}{dx} \, \left( \frac{x^{2n+1}}{n+1}\right) \\
&= \frac{2n+1}{n+1} \, x^{2n}.
\end{align}

Each of these views yields the same result.